# Error "Cannot resolve symbol R" after updating firebase version

Tags: android, firebase

I was working on an older version of firebase and everything was working fine, then i updated it to 11.8.0 but i got errors all over the project

- 'Cannot resolve symbol R' in the java classes
- errors from v26\values-v26.xml file in the screenshoot:

[image: xml file errors]

here is my gradle files:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I rebuild the project and cleaned it but nothing was solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your gradle from version 25 to 26

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

And dependencies

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

Comment: downgrade the firebase lib